# System is stuttering from time to time

Tags: kernel

It happens just when I watch videos? No, it happens always regardless if I'm watching videos or listening some music.

I'm using [ukuu](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html) to update the Linux kernel but things keep the same even with the latest kernel.

My sys specs are:

lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: neon
Description:    KDE neon User Edition 5.9
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

uname -a:

```
Linux note 4.9.8-040908-generic #201702040431 SMP Sat Feb 4 09:32:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  14
bnep                   20480  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
intel_rapl             20480  0
videodev              172032  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
coretemp               16384  0
snd_soc_rt5640        118784  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_soc_core          221184  1 snd_soc_rt5640
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
rtl8723be              90112  0
btusb                  45056  0
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
bluetooth             557056  41 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
snd_pcm               102400  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_core
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
mac80211              774144  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              589824  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cryptd                 20480  3 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
intel_cstate           20480  0
mei_me                 36864  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  23 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
serio_raw              16384  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_soc_sst_acpi
dw_dmac                16384  0
kvm_intel             200704  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
tpm_infineon           20480  0
elan_i2c               36864  0
8250_dw                16384  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
kvm                   585728  1 kvm_intel
mac_hid                16384  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
intel_smartconnect     16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915                 1261568  26
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               139264  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
r8169                  81920  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm                   339968  11 i915,drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  1 r8169
wmi                    16384  0
video                  40960  1 i915
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
fjes                   28672  0
```

lshw:

```
VISO: você deveria executar este programa como superusuário.
note                      
    descrição: Computer
    largura: 64 bits
    capacidades: vsyscall32
  *-core
       descrição: Motherboard
       ID físico: 0
     *-memory
          descrição: Memória do sistema
          ID físico: 0
          tamanho: 3838MiB
     *-cpu
          produto: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
          fabricante: Intel Corp.
          ID físico: 1
          informações do barramento: cpu@0
          tamanho: 1646MHz
          capacidade: 2600MHz
          largura: 64 bits
          capacidades: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
     *-pci
          descrição: Host bridge
          produto: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
          fabricante: Intel Corporation
          ID físico: 100
          informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:00.0
          versão: 09
          largura: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuração: driver=hsw_uncore
          recursos: irq:0
        *-display
             descrição: VGA compatible controller
             produto: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 2
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
             versão: 09
             largura: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuração: driver=i915 latency=0
             recursos: irq:44 memória:f7800000-f7bfffff memória:e0000000-efffffff porta de E/S:f000(tamanho=64) memória:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             descrição: Audio device
             produto: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 3
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:03.0
             versão: 09
             largura: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             recursos: irq:47 memória:f7e14000-f7e17fff
        *-usb:0
             descrição: USB controller
             produto: 8 Series USB xHCI HC
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 14
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:14.0
             versão: 04
             largura: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             recursos: irq:40 memória:f7e00000-f7e0ffff
        *-communication
             descrição: Communication controller
             produto: 8 Series HECI #0
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 16
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:16.0
             versão: 04
             largura: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=mei_me latency=0
             recursos: irq:45 memória:f7e1d000-f7e1d01f
        *-multimedia:1
             descrição: Audio device
             produto: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 1b
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             versão: 04
             largura: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             recursos: irq:46 memória:f7e10000-f7e13fff
        *-pci:0
             descrição: PCI bridge
             produto: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 1c
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             versão: e4
             largura: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:16 porta de E/S:2000(tamanho=4096) memória:df200000-df3fffff porta de E/S:df400000(tamanho=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             descrição: PCI bridge
             produto: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 1c.2
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             versão: e4
             largura: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:18 porta de E/S:e000(tamanho=4096) memória:f7d00000-f7dfffff
           *-network
                descrição: Interface sem fio
                produto: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                ID físico: 0
                informações do barramento: pci@0000:02:00.0
                nome lógico: wlp2s0
                versão: 00
                serial: 40:e2:30:c0:42:9f
                largura: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capacidades: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuração: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.9.8-040908-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                recursos: irq:18 porta de E/S:e000(tamanho=256) memória:f7d00000-f7d03fff
        *-pci:2
             descrição: PCI bridge
             produto: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 1c.3
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             versão: e4
             largura: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:19 porta de E/S:d000(tamanho=4096) memória:f7c00000-f7cfffff
           *-generic
                descrição: Unassigned class
                produto: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                ID físico: 0
                informações do barramento: pci@0000:03:00.0
                versão: 01
                largura: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capacidades: bus_master cap_list rom
                configuração: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                recursos: irq:43 memória:f7c15000-f7c15fff memória:f7c00000-f7c0ffff
           *-network
                descrição: Ethernet interface
                produto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                ID físico: 0.1
                informações do barramento: pci@0000:03:00.1
                nome lógico: enp3s0f1
                versão: 12
                serial: 80:fa:5b:a0:8c:f2
                tamanho: 100Mbit/s
                capacidade: 1Gbit/s
                largura: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capacidades: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuração: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                recursos: irq:42 porta de E/S:d000(tamanho=256) memória:f7c14000-f7c14fff memória:f7c10000-f7c13fff
        *-usb:1
             descrição: USB controller
             produto: 8 Series USB EHCI #1
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 1d
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             versão: 04
             largura: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             recursos: irq:23 memória:f7e1b000-f7e1b3ff
        *-isa
             descrição: ISA bridge
             produto: 8 Series LPC Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 1f
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             versão: 04
             largura: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capacidades: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             recursos: irq:0
        *-storage
             descrição: SATA controller
             produto: 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 1f.2
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             versão: 04
             largura: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capacidades: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuração: driver=ahci latency=0
             recursos: irq:41 porta de E/S:f0b0(tamanho=8) porta de E/S:f0a0(tamanho=4) porta de E/S:f090(tamanho=8) porta de E/S:f080(tamanho=4) porta de E/S:f060(tamanho=32) memória:f7e1a000-f7e1a7ff
        *-serial DISPONÍVEL
             descrição: SMBus
             produto: 8 Series SMBus Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             ID físico: 1f.3
             informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             versão: 04
             largura: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuração: latency=0
             recursos: memória:f7e19000-f7e190ff porta de E/S:f040(tamanho=32)
     *-scsi
          ID físico: 2
          nome lógico: scsi1
          capacidades: emulated
        *-cdrom
             descrição: DVD-RAM writer
             produto: CDDVDW SU-208FB
             fabricante: TSSTcorp
             ID físico: 0.0.0
             informações do barramento: scsi@1:0.0.0
             nome lógico: /dev/cdrom
             nome lógico: /dev/cdrw
             nome lógico: /dev/dvd
             nome lógico: /dev/dvdrw
             nome lógico: /dev/sr0
             versão: SB00
             capacidades: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuração: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
AVISO: a saída pode ser incompleta e imprecisa, você deveria executar este programa como superusuário.
```

Today after a stutter I collected a message from dmesg saying:

```
[10629.280186] perf: interrupt took too long (2562 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 78000
```